# Reload window DOM after injecting php element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two different playlist in php file and I have two buttons playlist1 and playlist2.

```
<div class="player">
    <?php include ('playlist1.php');?>
    <?php include ('playlist2.php');?>
</div>
```

If I click **playlist1** in the homepage it has to reload and append the `<?php include ('playlist1.php');?>` before page loads.

If I click **playlist2** in the homepage it has to reload and append the `<?php include ('playlist2.php');?>` before page loads.

I tried something but no luck.

```
$( "playlist1" ).click(function() {
    var append_php = "<?php include ('playlist2.php');?>";
    $('#playlist').append("<div id='playlist2'>"+append_php+"</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to emit PHP directives in Javascript which will never work. Keep in mind that Javascript runs *on the client* (i.e. on a web browser on the user's machine) and PHP runs *on the server*. You, therefore, cannot render PHP directly on the client - it must be run on the server.

Running on the server requires you to either navigate to a different page (perhaps using a querystring to pick what playlist you wish to render) or look into using AJAX instead.

Given that you say:

> If I click playlist1 in the homepage it has to reload and append the  before page loads.
>
> If I click playlist2 in the homepage it has to reload and append the  before page loads.

I'd suggest you change your PHP to look something like the following:

```
<div class="player">
    <?php
        $playlist = isset($_GET['playlist']) ? $_GET['playlist'] : '1';
        include("playlist".$playlist."php")
    ?>
</div>
<a href="index.php?playlist=1">Playlist 1</a>
<a href="index.php?playlist=2">Playlist 2</a>
```

This basically inspects the querystring and then renders whatever is in `playlist1.php` or `playlist2.php` based upon what you pass. By default it renders `playlist1.php`. It assumes that the PHP file you're running is called `index.php`.

Comment: Thanks, How can i reload page when user click either playlist 1 or playlist 2

Comment: @techies the links beneath the `<div class="player">...</div>` would do that